# Ruby C Extensions - Add System Frameworks

Tags: c, ruby, accelerate-framework, ruby-c-extension

I am building a C extension that uses the Mac OSX [Accelerate Framework](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man7/Accelerate.7.html).
When I compile normal C code I include the header

```
#include <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>
```

and compile with

```
llvm-gcc -framework Accelerate code.c -o code
```

The flag takes care of finding the right libraries. 
Can I do something similar for a ruby C extension? I assume I need to include the framework in `extconf.rb` but I don't know how.

Comment: I _think_ you just need to add [`have_framework('Accelerate')`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/mkmf/rdoc/MakeMakefile.html#method-i-have_framework) to `extconf.rb` and it will set up the command to use the appropriate `-framework` switch.

Comment: It works. If you add an answer I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a framework in a Ruby extension, you need to use the [`have_framework`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/mkmf/rdoc/MakeMakefile.html#method-i-have_framework) method in your `extconf.rb`. This will add the appropriate command line options in the Makefile.

In your case you want:

```
have_framework('Accelerate')
```